# error: package org.hibernate.internal does not exist

Tags: jboss7.x, ejb-3.0, netbeans-7

I have also included the this 'hibernate-core-4.0.0.Final-sources.jar' in ejb project.
but 'import org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl;' package is not import in Netbeans ID 7.4

error: cannot find symbol
            } else if (em.getDelegate() instanceof SessionImpl) {
  symbol:   class SessionImpl

Comment: Don't include any Hibernate libraries in your deployment. They are provided by the container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have resolved this issue by change the jboss server version. Changed
>   from Jboss4.2 to Jboss6.2 in netbeans property.
>   [image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you were working in jboss6 but selected jboss4 in netbeans for your project :P